# Nat Network on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, nat

Hi is it possible to make my host machine part of a virtualbox nat network?

I can make the 2 guests comunicating but not the host.

I can see the 2 guests have a pingable Gateway but i cant ping anything from the host even when configuring a host-only adapter, maybe because virtual box create it as host only.

[image: Here is a scheme of what i need.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two alternatives:

1. Configure the guests' network adapters as Bridged Adapters. This attaches the guests to the same subnet as the host. This way the guests are part of the network and can communicate with the outside world just as the host can.
2. Use Host-only networking. Configure the adapters as "Attached to Host-only Adapter". You will have to create a host-only network in VirtualBox's global settings (File → Preferences → Network → Host-only Networks), then attach the guests' adapters to this network. The guests can only communicate with each other and with the host.

Comment: ty but i had already done your first option, i'll still mark and upvote your answer for the good effort ;D